# adding item search to for loop

Tags: java, arrays, string

Currently I have

```
public void sellAllBut() {
Iterator<String> i = inventory.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
  if (!i.next().equalsIgnoreCase("pickaxe")) {
    i.remove();
  }   
}
```

}

right now it only removes the item from the inventory.class string array. How can I add it so that when it removes that item, it adds the gold amount using inventory.goldCoins += intvalue;

my int values are

```
    //ores
    int copperoPrice = 150;
    int ironoPrice = 200;
    int steeloPrice = 350;
    int goldoPrice = 500;
    int diamondoPrice = 700;
    int pickaxePrice = 500;
```

and the items that get put into the array are:

```
    String ore = null;


     if (oreFind <= 50) {
         ore = "Copper ore";

         } 

     if (oreFind >=51) {
         if (oreFind <= 70) {
             ore = "Iron ore";
         }
     }
     if (oreFind >=71) {
         if (oreFind <= 90) {
             ore = "Steel ore";
         }
     }
     if (oreFind >=91) {
         if (oreFind <= 99) {
             ore = "Gold ore";
         }
     }
     if (oreFind == 100) { 
             ore = "Diamond ore";
     }
```

after the string value is set to the ore i use this line of code to add it to my inventory string array:

inventory.addInventory(ore);

so for example my inventory can have : [Diamond ore, Gold ore, Gold ore]

what can i do to give a price to each of these and put it in the sellAllBut void?

Answer (score 0):

this is a little confusing but wouldn't you simply be doing something like;

For each ore price, create an object instead that has the ore name and it's price.

Then have each of those objects inherit from an interface.

Now you have a collection you can search on using it's name and LINQ.

So then in your loop you can;

```
public void sellAllBut() {
Iterator<String> i = inventory.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
  if (!i.next().equalsIgnoreCase("pickaxe")) {
    sellAllBut += ores.where(x => x.name == i).firstOrDefault();
    i.remove();
  }   
}
```

The above is totally untested but the method I think is what you are looking for.  Let me know if you need more than this or even if this is not what you were looking for.

**edit**

Actually, you don't need the interface.